# Issue with C# Microsoft Bot Hero Card Post Back Functionality

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am creating a simple movie ticket booking application where I use a hero card to select a movie and upon selecting a movie, a confirmation message with YES/NO option will be displayed. 
Here is the high level code flow
1. MovieDialog which has the HeroCard to select a movie
2. ConfirmationDialog to show the confirmation option with YES/NO

Issue:
I have a resume method (OnOptionConfirmationSelected) in ConfirmationDialog which should execute after the prompt option is selected but this method gets called immediately after clicking the movie button. Can you please check the code and tell me where the issue is?

### Code:

### MovieDialog

```
[Serializable]
public class MovieDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        //return Task.CompletedTask;
    }





    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        Activity activity = (Activity)context.Activity;
        string szMovieDate = "";
        string szMovieLanguage = "";
        string szMovieName = "";
        context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.MovieDateKey, out szMovieDate);
        context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.LanguageKey, out szMovieLanguage);


        if (!(context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.MovieNameKey, out szMovieName)))
        {
            var reply = context.MakeMessage();
            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            reply.Attachments = GetCardsAttachments(context);
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
        else
        {
            context.ConversationData.SetValue(ContextConstants.MovieNameKey, Convert.ToString(activity.Text));
            await context.Forward(new ConfirmationDialog(), this.ResumeAfterConfirmationDialog, activity, CancellationToken.None);
            //await context.PostAsync(activity);
        }

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        //Below is Test line
        //await context.PostAsync("List of movies in " + Convert.ToString(activity.Text));
        //If Context Forward is there then ContextWait is not needed. 
        //context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private static IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments(IDialogContext context)
    {
        List<Attachment> oImageAttachment = new List<Attachment>();

        Dictionary<string, string> lstmovie = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        lstmovie.Add("Movie1", @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
        lstmovie.Add("Movie2", @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
        lstmovie.Add("Movie3", @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
        lstmovie.Add("Movie4", @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
        lstmovie.Add("Movie5", @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> movielist in lstmovie)
        {
            oImageAttachment.Add(
                GetHeroCard(
                    movielist.Key,
                    new CardImage(url: movielist.Value),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Book","",movielist.Key))
            );
        }

        context.ConversationData.SetValue(ContextConstants.MovieNameKey, "");
        return oImageAttachment;
    }

    private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string title, CardImage cardImage, CardAction cardAction)
    {
        var heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = title,
            Images = new List<CardImage>() { cardImage },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>() { cardAction },
        };

        return heroCard.ToAttachment();
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterConfirmationDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        // Store the value that NewOrderDialog returned. 
        // (At this point, new order dialog has finished and returned some value to use within the root dialog.)
        Activity activity = (Activity)context.Activity;
        var optionSelected = activity.Text;

        //await context.PostAsync(Convert.ToString(resultFromNewOrder));

        // Again, wait for the next message from the user.
        context.Done(optionSelected);
    }
}
```

---

### ConfirmationDialog

```
[Serializable]
public class ConfirmationDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {


        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        //return Task.CompletedTask;
    }





    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        Activity activity = (Activity)context.Activity;


        this.ShowOptions(context);

        //Below is Test line
        //context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.MovieDateKey, out szMovieDate);
        //await context.PostAsync("List of movies in " + Convert.ToString(activity.Text));
        //If Context Forward is there then ContextWait is not needed. 
        //context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private void ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
    {
        string szMovieDate = "";
        string szMovieLanguage = "";
        string szMovieName = "";
        context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.MovieDateKey, out szMovieDate);
        context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.LanguageKey, out szMovieLanguage);
        context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.MovieNameKey, out szMovieName);

        string szConfirmationMessage = "";
        szConfirmationMessage = String.Format("You have booked ticket for movie {0} for this date {1}", szMovieName, szMovieDate);
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionConfirmationSelected, new List<string>() { "Yes", "No" }, szConfirmationMessage, "Not a valid option", 3);
        //context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task OnOptionConfirmationSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        Activity activity = (Activity)context.Activity;
        var optionSelected = activity.Text;

        if (optionSelected.ToUpper() == "YES" || optionSelected.ToUpper() == "NO")
        {
            //await context.PostAsync(Convert.ToString(optionSelected));
            context.Done(optionSelected);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the `MessageReceivedAsync` method of the `MovieDialog` you are doing a `context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);` outside the if/else clause an so you are waiting in that dialog and at the same time you are forwarding the message to the `ConfirmationDialog`. You should move the wait line inside the if, right after the `PostAync`